# Time difference rails (where DATE mysql)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

How I can write this on SQL
It works fine but returns an array and I need ActiveRecord

```
scope :no_test, ->{ select{|el| (el.premium_expiration_date - 1.hour) > el.purchase_date} }
```

Something like this

```
.where('DATE(premium_expiration_date) - 3600 > DATE(purchase_date)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `date_sub`

```
.where('date_sub(premium_expiration_date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) > purchase_date')
```